# Pass by reference versus value in variable versus array element

Tags: java, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I know this question apparently has many duplicates like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value) and [here](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2077424/learn-java/learn-java-does-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value.html).

My question is different though.

Consider the following example:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void test(int a, int b) {
        System.out.println("In test() at start: "+a+" "+b);
        int temp=a;
        a=b;
        b=temp;
        System.out.println("In test() at end: "+a+" "+b);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int a=1, b=2;
        System.out.println("a: "+a+" b: "+b);

        test(a, b);
        System.out.println("a: "+a+" b: "+b);
    }
}
```

[The output that I get](https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler#&togetherjs=VyEEoswc5J) for the above snippet is:

> a: 1 b: 2
>   In test() at start: 1 2
>   In test() at end: 2 1
>   a: 1 b: 2

This shows that the original values of `a` and `b` in main() have *not been swapped* when I called `test()`, thereby implying (if I understand correctly) that it was *passed by value*.

Now, consider the following code snippet:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void test(int[] arr) {
        System.out.println(arr[2]);
        arr[2]=20;
        System.out.println(arr[2]);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int[] arr={0,1,2,3,4,5};
        System.out.println(arr[2]);

        test(arr);
        System.out.println(arr[2]);
    }
}
```

[The output that I get](https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler#&togetherjs=KEloiQJNwA) for this code snippet is:

> 2
>   2
>   20
>   20

This shows that the value at `arr[2]` was changed in the original array in `main()`, thereby denoting (if I understand correctly) that the array *was passed by reference*.

Could someone please point out what is going on?  Why does it show different behaviors?

Thanks!

Comment: All arrays are passed be reference, by default variables are passed by value. If you were to use `Integer` it would behave similarly

Comment: I come from a C++ background.  So, if some one explains from _that perspective_ it would be very helpful for me.

Comment: @Mitchel0022, okay, got your point.  `Integer` as the datatype of a variable or an array element, you mean?

Comment: Either, `Integer` is a object, therefore it will be passed by reference and changing it in the function will change it permanently. `int` will only change in the scope of the function

Comment: @Mitchel0022, okay.  So to conclude, arrays and objects are passed by reference; everything else by value.  What about containers?  I think reference again (because they contain nothing but objects)?

Comment: Containers are reference

Comment: Thank you, @Mitchel0022.  It is very helpful for someone who comes from a C++ background like me.  If you convert it into an answer, I would be glad to accept it.

Comment: Its not large enough of a question to justify an answer, but glad I could help

Comment: @StaticBeagle, guess what, the links that I have included at the beginning of the question is the exact same that you mention (maybe you didn't check those).  And, my _entire post_ explains how it is different than that link.  Do you still think that it is a duplicate?!

Comment: @RakeshKarandikar yes it is a duplicate and the accepted answer is not entirely  correct. Everything in java is pass by value as pointed out in the answer in the link I provided. Read the answer in the old question carefully and you will realize that it is indeed a duplicate.

Comment: @StaticBeagle, could you please elaborate?  The opening paragraph itself says _Unfortunately, they decided to call the location of an object a "reference". When we pass the value of an object, we are passing the reference to it. This is confusing to beginners._ - it is talking about objects.  As per Mitchel0022's comments above, this is right; but variables of primitive data types are passed by value.  Could you please confirm?

Comment: @RakeshKarandikar it creates a copy of the reference and passes that copy by value. Say you have `int[] array = ...` and you pass this array to a function `func(int[] arrayPrime)`, now inside the function `arrayPrime` points to the same location as `array`, thus `arrayPrime[2]` alters the value stored in `array[2]` but what happens if I do `arrayPrime = new int[]` inside the function? Now `arrayPrime` is no longer a reference to `array`. Think of a function passing a pointer `(int* p)`, C++ will pass a copy of than pointer to the function, thus passes the pointer by value. Clear as mud? =]

Comment: @StaticBeagle, absolutely clear.  Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Primitive datatype variables will be passed by value.
Object datatype variables will be passed by reference. 
Array is Object datatype, so it will be passed by reference.

Comment: This is incorrect.  Please read the canonical duplicate link.  It's a subtle but _very important_ distinction, because in Java there are only primitives and references.  Everything is passed by value.

Comment: @JimGarrison, what about the array then?  As Mitchell0022 pointed out in the comments above, I think they are passed by reference, because that explains the output and observation of the second code snippet.  Could you please elaborate to help me understand?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just getting confused with the array part.

**Array in java is a special `object`** that contains references to other objects.
You can very well change those "*child*" object's values as with any Object.

Remember this thumb rule that I keep to avoid confusion:

> It doesn't matter what you do directly with the object but what you
>   do inside it

Meaning that if you do some changes inside of any sub-object (or array item in your case) you'd see the *side effects* of it in your caller.